# How to generate list of n sized lists from given list

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say we are given a list,

```
var l = [50, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60]
```

and a random number `n`.

I need to create a function that return all possible lists of length `n`.

If `n = 3`,

```
[50,55,57],[50,55,58],[50,55,60],[50,57,58],[50,57,60],[50,58,60],[55,57,58],[55,57,60],[55,58,60],[57,58,60]
```

**EDIT**

I could not add the complete output array, because I don't know how to generate it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can `n` ever be greater than the input array size? I'm assuming not.

Comment: The desired array does not represent the solution for your input. There is a 60 there and there's no 60 in the input array.

Comment: n can't be greater than input array size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n` is less than the size of the input array, you could do this:

```js
var soln = []
function generateListsFromSize(array, n, offset=0, current=[]) {
   if (current.length == n){
     soln.push(current.map(elem => elem))
     return
   } 

   for (var i=offset; i < array.length; i++) {
      current.push(array[i]);
      generateListsFromSize(array, n, i + 1, current);
      current.pop();
   }
}

generateListsFromSize([50, 55, 57, 58, 60], 3)
console.log(soln)
```

The idea is to maintain an array, in this case, `current`, and try all the different scenarios by [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

Comment: Your solution array contains 125 entries. The desired array contains 10 entries.

Comment: I updated my solution. I was quite confused about that desired output, because it looked like an incorrect output, it has items that doesn't exist in the input array.

Answer (score 1):

That's called recursion:

```
 const arr = [50, 55, 56, 57, 58]

 const list = function (n, index, tempArr) {
 // Return of recursion
 if (tempArr.length == n) {
    console.log(tempArr)
    return
 }

 // Recursion
 while (index < arr.length) {
    tempArr.push(arr[index])
    list(n, ++index, tempArr)
    tempArr.pop()
 }

}

list(3, 0, [])
```

Comment: How is this different than the other solution?

Comment: I saw your code and the idea of mine is the same. Just implement a bit